# How to check whether a PHP function is empty?

Tags: php, function

Suppose I've a PHP function returning some values.

```
<?php
function wpse_20131026() {
  $var = "I'm a function";
  return $var;
}
?>
```

How can I check whether it's returning empty or not? I tried the following:

```
<?php
if( !empty( wpse_20131026() ) ) {
  //do_something;
}
?>
```

But it's warning me:

> **Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context**

Comment: Also, read this useful topic: http://kunststube.net/isset/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) checks variables, but not values in php versions, that less than 5.5.

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

So you may use a temporary variable:

```
$var = wpse_20131026();

if(!empty($var)) {
    // do_something with $var
}
```

Or boolean evaluation directly (without `empty()` call):

```
if(wpse_20131026()) {
    // do_something
}
```